# Ionic 3 - Sqlite Save Camera Photo

Tags: javascript, angular, sqlite, ionic-framework

I have this table that I use for saving image urls locally. I thing I want is that when the user is offline, save the pictures taken from the camera or the library and store it locally in sqlite. Then when he gets online sync it to the server.

```
CREATE TABLE   Media (
    MediaId    TEXT  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    MediaType   INTEGER,
    MediaUrl TEXT,
    Flag INT

);
```

I have something like this in .ts file. I want a way to store the image data as well as its url.

```
    this.camera.getPicture({
                    quality: 100,
                    destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                    encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                    mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
                    allowEdit: true
                }).then((imageData) => {
                    try {                              
                          this.OpenCustomerGallery(this.imageService.b64toFile(...
                    }
                    catch (err) {
                        alert(err.message);
                    }

                }, (err) => {
                    //console.log((err));
                });
```

Comment: did you successfully stored the camera pictures to the SQLite offline?

Comment: Yes, I answered my own question

Answer (score 0):

I just saved the base64 string as TEXT in SQLite and re-upload the image once the connection comes back.